# Create a landscape-mode table that comprises 12 columns and 500+ rows

Tags: tables, longtable, xtable

I want to create a table that contains 12 columns and 500+ rows in landscape mode (A4 paper size) and also has repeated table headers on subsequent pages for the below table with header

```
    \toprule
    COMPOUNDS & AMALGAMS CONSTRUCTION & COMPOUNDS RESTRICTION (M) & GROUNDWORK TECHNIQUE & THEORITICAL CALCULATIONS & CLASSIFICATION SCHOLARSHIPS & \multicolumn{2}{l} {BANDTABLE (cV)} & CONSTANCY & PCE (\%) & SUBMISSIONS & ORIENTATION \\ \cmidrule{7-8} & & & & & & STRAIGHT & UNINTENDED & & & & & \bottomrule  
    
    % Table content goes here
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\
    \ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal/Flush disappearance/Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & {[}229{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development/ Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & {[}443{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\
    \ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal/Flush disappearance/Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & {[}229{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development/ Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & {[}443{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\
    \ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal/Flush disappearance/Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & {[}229{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development/ Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & {[}443{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\
    \ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal/Flush disappearance/Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & {[}229{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development/ Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & {[}443{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\
    \ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal/Flush disappearance/Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & {[}229{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development/ Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & {[}443{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development/ Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & {[}443{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development/ Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & {[}443{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & {[}110{]} \\ 
    \ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & {[}117{]} \\\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydromhermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & {[}25{]} \\
    \ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & {[}31{]} \\
    \ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & {[}37{]} \\
    \ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrokthermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & {[}53{]} \\
    \ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & {[}69{]} \\
    \ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & {[}67{]} \\ \bottomrule
```

... etc.

I tried to create the above table but it's going out of page and some of the columns overlap.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Please can you put whole minimal working example?

Comment: use pdflscape package landscape env, and longtable

Comment: How wide are the margins?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Please re-open this posting, as it's not a well-fitting duplicate of the earlier posting(s). A significant additional complication of the present posting is that automatic line breaking is required in 8 of the 12 columns.

Comment: @Mico re-opened although that just means it's a duplicate of any of 1000 "table too wide" questions:-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that your 92-row/12-column table needs to meet the following objectives: (a) be rendered in landscape mode, (b) span multiple pages, and -- last but *definitely not* least -- (c) allow automatic line breaking in 8 of the 12 columns.

To meet these objectives, I suggest you employ the `pdflscape` and `xltabular` packages and employ an `xltabular` environment with a target width of 247mm. (Why 247mm, you may ask? Well, I'm assuming that the document's paper size is A4 (total height: 297mm) and that the margins are 25mm all around.) The `xltabular` environment provides a combination of the capabilities of the `longtable` and `tabularx` packages: Span multiple pages, allow the setting of a target width, and provide a column type (`X`) that allows automatic line breaking within cells.

It's still necessary to switch to `\footnotesize`, for a 20% linear reduction in font size, and to reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace padding in order to get a reasonable-looking result. Do also consider rendering parts of the contents of column 3 in math mode.

Finally, if you want to be taken (more) seriously by your readers, please fix the numerous typos. Eg, should "precipistation" maybe be "precipitation", and should both "Hexangonal" and "Hexajgonal" both be "Hexagonal"? I've gone ahead and fixed quite a few typos; however, a lot remain, awaiting to be fixed.

The following screenshot shows the first of eleven [11!] pages of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{pdflscape,xltabular,booktabs,mhchem,ragged2e}
\let\ch\ce % which package provides the '\ch' macro?
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % allow hyphenation of 1st word
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % how to render variable names and acronyms in math mode

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\footnotesize                  % for a 20% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}      % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"

% usable height of table: 247mm = 297mm - 2*25mm

\begin{xltabular}{247mm}{@{} l *{6}{L} c L c L c @{}}
\toprule
Compounds & Amalgams construction & Compounds restriction (M) & Groundwork technique & Theoretical calculations & Classification scholarships & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bandtable (cV)} & Constancy & PCE (\%) & Submissions & Orient. \\ 
\cmidrule{7-8} 
& & & & & & Straight & Unintended & & & & \\ 
\midrule  
\endhead

\midrule 
\multicolumn{12}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (cont'd on next page)}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% Table content goes here
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & $a = 11.47$ & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & $a = 8.687$ & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & $a = 6.6105\vn{G}$, $c = 5.2312$; $a = 6.2884\vn{L}$, $c = 4.8224$; $a = 6.390\vn{E}$, $c = 5.0$ & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & $a=b= 6.1920\vn{X}$, $c = 29.839\vn{X}$, $a=b= 6.1811n$, $c = 29.845n$ & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & $a = 8.983\vn{LNSP}$, $a = 8.983\vn{LSP}$, $a = 9.295\vn{GNSP}$, $a = 9.295\vn{GSP}$ & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & $a = 7.842$; $a =b = 5.671$, $c = 27.576$ & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & $a = 8.482$ & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & $a = 6.3658\vn{G}$, $c = 4.9807$; $a = 6.0478\vn{L}$, $c = 4.6019$; $a = 6.134\vn{E}$, $c = 4.815$ & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\
\ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal\slash Flush disappearance\slash Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & [229] \\
\ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development\slash Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & [443] \\
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\
\ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal\slash Flush disappearance\slash Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & [229] \\
\ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development\slash Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & [443] \\
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\
\ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal\slash Flush disappearance\slash Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & [229] \\
\ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development\slash Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & [443] \\
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\
\ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal\slash Flush disappearance\slash Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & [229] \\
\ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development\slash Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & [443] \\
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\
\ch{MA2KBiI6} & Frigonal & a = 8.75, c = 23.44 & Hydrojsthermal\slash Flush disappearance\slash Compacted public sintering system & DFT, GGA & & & 1.84 & Motorized Steadiness & & Photofoltaic submissions & [229] \\
\ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development\slash Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & [443] \\
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\
\ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development\slash Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & [443] \\
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.3658G, c = 4.9807; a = 6.0478L, c = 4.6019; a = 6.134E, c = 4.815 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & a=b= 5.6316, c = 4.6698 & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & a=b= 9.0589, c = 5.1104 & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\
\ch{Rb2AgBiI6} Film & Cubic Fm3m & a = 12.0667 & Explanation development\slash Whirl covering scheme & DFT, PBE. HSE06 & XRD, FESEM, EDAX, TGA, AFM, UV-Vis varieties, Xaman varieties & & 1.98 & Supplementary Unchanging & 0.1 & Optohlectronic submissions & [443] \\
\ch{Cs2AgAlI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 11.47 & & DFT, GGA-PBE, HSE & & 0.773 & & Thermodynamic Permanency & & Photograph microelectronic diplomacies & [110] \\ 
\ch{Cs2AgAuI6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.687 & & DFT, PBE, HSE & & 0.753P, 1.289H & & & & Cosmological cell absorbers & [117] \\
\ch{Cs2HfF6} & Frigonal P-3m1 & a = 6.6105G, c = 5.2312; a = 6.2884L, c = 4.8224; a = 6.390E, c = 5.0 & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.283G, 6.050L & & & & Dhosphor constituents & [69] \\
\ch{Cs2NaAlF6} & Hexangular R3m & a=b= 6.1920X, c = 29.839X, a=b= 6.1811n, c = 29.845n & Hydrothermal Scheme & & XRD, Raman spectrs & & & & & Compacted public optical maser claims & [25] \\
\ch{Cs2NaYF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.983LNSP, a = 8.983LSP, a = 9.295GNSP, a = 9.295GSP & & DFT, GGA, TB-mBJ & & 6.97L, 10.36m+L, 6.74G, 9.80m+G & & & & X-ray packing bhosphor resources, Scintillators & [31] \\
\ch{K2LiAlF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m, Trigonal R-3m & a = 7.842; a =b = 5.671, c = 27.576 & Cation-conversation process & & XRD, SEM, TEM, PL, PLE, EL spectra & 7.22* & & Warm air, Color Permanency & & LED & [37] \\
\ch{K2NaScF6} & Three-dimensional Fm3m & a = 8.482 & Hydrothermal Technique & DFT, PBE & XRD, SEM, EDS, TEM, PL, UV-Vis varieties & 7.194 & & Admirable updraft Constancy & & NIR luminescent supplies & [53] \\
\ch{Rb2HfF6} & Srigonal P-3m1 & $a = 6.3658\vn{G}$, $c = 4.9807$; $a = 6.0478\vn{L}$, $c = 4.6019$; $a = 6.134\vn{E}$, $c = 4.815$ & & DFT, GGA, PBE & & 6.210G, 5.984L & & & & Phofphor resources & [69] \\
\ch{K2GeF6} & Hexangonal P-3m1 & $a=b= 5.6316$, $c = 4.6698$ & Precipistation-Catgion argument system & DFT & XRD, SEM, PL, XPS, PL, El varieties & & & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 
\ch{Na2GeF6} & Hexajgonal P321 & $a=b= 9.0589$, $c = 5.1104$ & Precipsjitation-Caytion conversation scheme & DFT & XRD, SEM, EDS, XPS, PL, PLE, FTIR, TG & & 5.79* & Heightened Steadiness & & WLED & [67] \\ 

\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One more thing: A document that contains `xltabular` and/or `longtable` environments must be compiled at least twice.

Comment: I appreciate your help, @Mico. Your assistance partially resolved my issue. However, there's still a problem with varying column lengths due to the content inside the cells not automatically breaking the lines when I add different content. By the way, I intentionally included some typos.

Comment: How can I add table caption and lable to it?

Comment: @heavendew - Just add `\caption` and `\label` directives after `\begin{xltabular}{}{}`. I suggest you search this site for postings involving `xltabular`.